# Incrementar valores dos inputs em +1 contendo letras e números usando JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho uma tabela com dados das folhas de cheques como: banco, conta, agencia e número da folha, estava tudo bem até agora, mas hoje um cliente veio com um talão do itau e nele tem 3 letras seguido de um hífen e a sequencia do número. exemplo: **ABC-7852**

Os números das folhas são sequenciais incremetado de +1, nas folhas do itaú as letras não são alteradas, testei usando a função `explode do php` e consegui fazer funcionar desconsiderando tudo antes do `(-)` e depois concatenando.

No `JQuery` consigo utilizar `explode` ou alguma função semelhante? Para repetir as letras em todas as linhas e incrementar apenas os valores numéricos.

```
ABC-7852
ABC-7853
ABC-7854
ABC-7855
```

segue o código atual.

```js
$(document).on('blur', '.ncheque', function() {
  var chqs = $('.ncheque');
  var index = null;
  var valor = parseInt(this.value);
  indice = chqs.index(this);
  if (valor) {
    $('.ncheque').each(function(index) {
      if (index > indice) {
        $(this).val(valor + index);
      }
    });
  } else {
    $('.ncheque').val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <!-- Text input-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="txtCh1"></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="txtCh1" name="txtCh1" type="text" placeholder="Folha cheque 1" class="form-control input-md ncheque">
      <input id="txtCh2" name="txtCh2" type="text" placeholder="Folha cheque 2" class="form-control input-md ncheque">
      <input id="txtCh3" name="txtCh3" type="text" placeholder="Folha cheque 3" class="form-control input-md ncheque">
      <input id="txtCh4" name="txtCh4" type="text" placeholder="Folha cheque 4" class="form-control input-md ncheque">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O correspondente em JavaScript ao `explode` do PHP é o `split`.

Para poderes usar ambos os casos de ter só numeros ou numeros depois de letras (com o separador `-`)  podes fazer assim:

```
  var partes = this.value.split('-');
  var valor = parseInt(partes[1] || partes[0]);
```

e mais tarde para colocar de volta podes ter esta lógica:

```
[partes[1] ? partes[0] : null, valor + index].filter(Boolean).join('-')
```

A ideia é colocar de novo `partes[0]` no caso de `partes[1]` existir.

Exemplo:

```js
$(document).on('blur', '.ncheque', function() {
  var chqs = $('.ncheque');
  var index = null;
  var partes = this.value.split('-');
  var valor = parseInt(partes[1] || partes[0]);
  indice = chqs.index(this);
  if (valor) {
    $('.ncheque').each(function(index) {
      if (index > indice) {
        $(this).val([partes[1] ? partes[0] : null, valor + index].filter(Boolean).join('-'));
      }
    });
  } else {
    $('.ncheque').val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <!-- Text input-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="txtCh1"></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="txtCh1" name="txtCh1" type="text" placeholder="Folha cheque 1" class="form-control input-md ncheque">
      <input id="txtCh2" name="txtCh2" type="text" placeholder="Folha cheque 2" class="form-control input-md ncheque">
      <input id="txtCh3" name="txtCh3" type="text" placeholder="Folha cheque 3" class="form-control input-md ncheque">
      <input id="txtCh4" name="txtCh4" type="text" placeholder="Folha cheque 4" class="form-control input-md ncheque">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio eu comecei programar direto em `JQuery` e não sabia que poderia inserir funções nativas dentro da função, pensava que o `JQ` tivesse suas próprias funções. Pensava que o `JQ` reescrevia todo o javascript. Meu raciocínio estava errado? isso?

Comment: @WagnerFernandoMomesso O jQuery é escrito em JavaScript por isso podes sempre usar JavaScript nativo. Trabalhar com arrays e objetos é melhor com ferramentas nativas. Mexer no DOM é mais fácil com jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

Use `split` (explode) e `join` (implode)

```js
var str = "ABC-7852";
var res = parseInt(str.split("-")[1]) + 1;
res = "ABC-" + res;
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

O nome da função é Split. Ela pode ser lida melhor neste [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).

Nela, você terá uma certa String, e poderá quebrá-la de acordo com o caractere que deseja, no seu caso, o " - (traço) ".

A função te retornará um Array de X tamanhos onde será quebrado sua string, no seu caso (ABC-7852), serão retornado um array de tamanho 2, mais ou menos assim:

Array[0] = ABC, Array[[1](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)] = 7852

Por fim, é só contatenar ambos e retornar a String que deseja, na ordem que deseja. Exemplo:

```
var string = "ABC-7852";
var retorno = string.split('-');
console.log(retorno);
```